# Где найти компонент если его нет в папке bin?

Tags: delphi

У меня отсутствует компонент `ServerSocket1`. (делфи 2007).

Где его взять, если в папке bin нету `ServerSocket1`?

Comment: компонент называется `TServerSocket`, а не `ServerSocket1`. Должен быть на вкладке `Internet`

Answer (score 2):

Идете в `Component -> Install packages`, жмете `add`, затем в папке `Bin` ищете `dclsockets70`.

После добавления новые два компонента появятся на панели компонентов `Internet`

Comment: dclsockets70. это помоему под delphi 7

Comment: Значит я ошибся